# Fragment instances Or Multiple Fragment (Android)

Tags: android

I want to display `multiples` `fragments` for each `day` in a `week`. The thing is that sometimes there are `no data` to be displayed in a `fragment`. (each fragment display the `school classes` that there are in a `day`). So it's it better to create `one fragment per day` and load them when `there are data` or have `only one fragment` with `multiples instances` but `different data` inside.

Comment: you want to display 7 fragments in a single activity you mean?

Comment: yeah either 7 fragments(monday,tuesday,etc...)  or less depending if there are data or one fragment (different  instances)

Comment: technically you can do that but, the purpose of the fragments are something else. You can use ListView/RecyclerView with appropriate adapter instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment is a group of reusable interface.

So, if your "fragments" will all look the same then it's just one fragment initialized with different data.

If there is no data for some particular instance just make all its UI invisible and write something like "No data" in the center. Or do not show that fragment at all.

Comment: So you suggest to use one fragment(since there are the same) but different  instances (not the same data inside )

Comment: Yes. I would make a data class like MyDayTask and then I would do MyDayFragment.newInstance(MyDayTask). And as they do it put the MyDayTask into the fragment's 'arguments' Bundle with setArguments()